# In an composite type array, how should I select first element of composite type for all entries in array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a composite type:

```
create type p as (a int, b int);
```

Then I created an table:

```
create table f(pv p[]);
```

Fill in value with it:

```
insert into f values(array[(10,20),(30,40)]::p[]);
insert into f values(array[(1,20)]::p[]);
```

Now what I want is a "select" statement that display element "a" for each entry in the array, the expected may be like:

```
|pv     |
|{10,30}|
|{1}    |
```

I've tired lots of statement combination but it doesn't provide the answer.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Shore

Comment: Accepted, sorry mate for the late accept ion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider adding an `id` column to your table, so that the grouping can be done on that id after `unnest`ing .

```
SELECT array_agg(a)
FROM f
    ,unnest(pv)
GROUP BY id;
```

Otherwise, you could group by the whole array

```
SELECT array_agg(a)
FROM f
    ,unnest(pv)
GROUP BY pv;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/349d2/5)